# Html5 Cache Manifest for online page load speed

Tags: html, cache-manifest

Just want to check whether cache manifest can help to improve online page load speed.
From what I google about this cache manifest, it enable web pages to load offline (resources such as css, js and img loaded from cache based on the manifest)
Is there any difference if I implement the cache manifest into my page and load the page online but the resources are loaded from the cache based on the manifest I have set?